How can I diagnose a stuck key on a MacBook Air?
The escape button on my macBook air m1 is acting like it has been pressed ( triggered without pressing it).
This happens multiple times randomly. it has been occurring a lot recently.
Do i need to get it fixed in a service centre?

I very strongly recommend against trying to fix this yourself unless you have experience in repairing Apple products.

It’s unlikely this is a purely mechanical problem but is there a chance you have debris under the key cap? I would expect other keys to be crunchy and visible signs of foreign materials, but sometimes a bit of fluff can get caught on the cleanest of keyboards.
It’s much more likely this is due to a failure in the switch circuitry. I would open the case and inspect for signs of liquid damage and then get a quote from a repair shop. That way you understand prices if you try to repair it yourself and end up damaging the mechanism physically and not solving it or forcing a proper replacement.

The easiest/first step is to get a can of compressed air and a gentle bristle brush (such as a toothbrush) and clean out under/around the key. You may be able to unstick or remove what is under there.
If that doesn't work the next step is to remove and clean it, which is better left to a repair shop if you are not familiar with how to remove the keycap.

Gentle cleaning with those tools rarely hurts @Stacks but I’ve not experienced many cases where the Apple silicon era keyboards have enough space to warrant canned air or enough clearance for a brush to do meaningful work with the keys on. I don’t recommend popping the caps off unless you’ve got prices for replacement parts and time to wait for them to ship.
